# how to use mysql-connector-c++ 8.0： Cannot connect to remote Alibaba cloud database hosted

Tags: c++, mysql, alibaba-cloud

Can anyone tell me the answer, I have been unable to eat for a few days, thank you for being my benefactor

I'm using the mysql-connector-c++ 8.0  to  mysql 8.0.x
I want to connect to a remote cloud database. After trying countless times, I have encountered great difficulties. Is there something wrong with my code? I am a newbie to msyql
The strange thing is that mysql - h xxx - root - p can be executed on the linux command
line, but it fails in c++ alone, and the error is always one:

```
CDK Error: Connection attempt to the server was aborted. Timeout of 10000 milliseconds was exceeded
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

using namespace mysqlx;

int main() {
    try {
        Session sess(SessionOption::USER, "root",
                     SessionOption::PWD, "123456",
                     SessionOption::HOST, "172.29.207.112",
                   //SessionOption::HOST, "rm-bp1qp1x588kzb49rf.mysql.rds.aliyuncs.com",
                     SessionOption::PORT, 33060,
                     SessionOption::DB, "demo");

        auto result = sess.sql("select * from person").execute();

        for (auto row : result.fetchAll()) {
            std::cout << row[0] << " " << row[1] << "\n";
        }
        
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `172.29.207.112` falls squarely in a network space for private networking? Can your host ping that address? Also, the commented-out hostname resolves to `172.29.207.114`, not `112`.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, I know these, this is the intranet ip of an intranet cloud database host. PING was successful. The commented line is another cloud database host, which only provides a link to connect to the database, and the specific intranet IP is unknown. Also, this code is successful if host is the local localhost. Moreover, the same intranet ip or link is successful in the command line, for example: mysql -h rm-bp1qp1x588kzb49rf.mysql.rds.aliyuncs.com -u root -p or mysql -h 172.29.207.xxx - u root -p

Comment: Your code specifies a non-standard port number 3306**0** instead of the standard port number 3306. I was under the assumption you passed this to your `mysql` calls as well but it is clear you do not.

Comment: In mysql-connector-c++: The requirement is 33060, if I change it to 3306, or another error occurs. If you build a mysql server on this machine, the host is changed to localhost, and it is still 33060, which is successful. Yes. In the mysql command line it is 3306, in this code it is 33060, the two are equivalent, this is my understanding

Comment: Okay, apparently 33060 is the "x protocol port", whatever that may be. Can you establish a connection to that port normally using, say, `nc` ? Perhaps you forgot to configure a firewall setting or somesuch.. Or maybe the remote server is not listening on that port.

Comment: Finally figured it out, the problem is not with us, thank you very much for answering me, your answer helped me a lot！

Answer (score 1):

I finally know the answer. The reason is that the cloud database provider does not support 33060 of X Protocol. Currently, Alibaba Cloud does not support it. I learned this from the intelligent problem robot, but it is not mentioned in the document. Alibaba Cloud should update documentation! !